# React bootstrap 4 modal window close button bad formatting

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying make modal window in reactjs with bootstrap 4. When I use bootstrap 4 I have problem with css formatting with close button. When I use bootstrap 3 css are ok. 
There is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jyq2zxlj6) . Thank you for advice.

Comment: `When I use bootstrap 4 I have problem with css formatting with close button` what is the problem? what do you see? what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style

```
.modal-header {
  display: block;
}
```

The `display : flex` on the model-header is causing this issue. So override this style.

[Updated Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vjxjko4j23)